# Specific links do not pass PCA test

Tags: forms

I have a Drupal 7 site. It is HTTPS enabled. When I do a PCA compliance test, some of the links that refer to /sites/default/files/styles/* fail the test. The fail message says "..plain text information passed on request...".

Inside the styles folder I have some other folders where images are saved when I create content for the site. I added an .httaccess file inside /styles folder to re-write all requests on that folder or sub folders to https. The PCA test passes. However, this brought another issue: I can not save any images inside /styles folder or its sub folders. I get a Drupal error "Permission denied".

The folders permission is read,write,execute for owner and group.
Can anyone help me with this issue?